# Thunderbird hanging on 'Sending login information' with Gmail IMAP

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

We have a couple of Windows 7 desktops running the latest version of Thunderbird. They are trying to connect to Gmail via IMAP, which has worked fine up until today.

One of the desktops now seems to hang when connecting to IMAP, showing a 'sending login information' message in the status bar. I know the users details were correct, because I was able to login via a web browser to the Gmail webmail page. I then changed the users password, which caused Thunderbird to prompt that the authentication failed. When I entered the new password, it was accepted and Thunderbird hung again with the same message.

I turned on IMAP logging, which produced the following output (I have replaced the IP and email address with REMOVED):

```
5852[b00e430]: ImapThreadMainLoop entering [this=84f800]
0[80f140]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:SetupWithUrl: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL: entering
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL:imap://REMOVED@imap.gmail.com:993/select%3E%5EINBOX:  = currentUrl
5852[b00e430]: ReadNextLine [stream=9deb668 nb=69 needmore=0]
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * OK Gimap ready for requests from REMOVED dq3mb183348694pbb
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:SendData: 1 capability
5852[b00e430]: ReadNextLine [stream=9deb668 nb=156 needmore=0]
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
5852[b00e430]: ReadNextLine [stream=9deb668 nb=45 needmore=0]
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 1 OK Thats all she wrote! dq3mb183348694pbb
5852[b00e430]: try to log in
5852[b00e430]: IMAP auth: server caps 0x80C1625, pref 0x4, failed 0x1006, avail caps 0x0
5852[b00e430]: (GSSAPI = 0x1000000, CRAM = 0x0, NTLM = 0x20000, MSN =  0x0, PLAIN = 0x100000, LOGIN = 0x0, old-style IMAP login = 0x200000)auth external IMAP login = 0x0
5852[b00e430]: trying auth method 0x1000
5852[b00e430]: got new password
5852[b00e430]: IMAP: trying auth method 0x1000
5852[b00e430]: PLAIN auth
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:SendData: 2 authenticate plain
5852[b00e430]: ReadNextLine [stream=9deb668 nb=4 needmore=0]
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: + 
5852[b00e430]: 84f800:imap.gmail.com:NA:SendData: Logging suppressed for this command (it probably contained authentication information)
```

Does anyone know what else I can try to resolve this?